# my div tag is unclickable when there is an IMG tag underneath in ie7 ie8

Tags: jquery, css

Let's uncomplicate things

http://jsfiddle.net/Hh7Mn/

```
<div style="width:100px; height:200px; border:10px solid; cursor:pointer; position:absolute; z-index:99;">dsdsfdsfsdfdsfdsf</div>



<img style="z-index:0;" id="default_image" src="http://www.takeprideinutah.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/trees.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Why is the center of the div unselectable and undetectable in ie?

EDIT:

Sorry the code is now the same on both jsfiddle and stack

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot or image of the current result? It would be much easier to assess your problem.

Comment: ...or a link to the page would be helpful.

Comment: your jsfiddle is completely different to the code you included in your question. How can we test accurately?

Comment: thanks. I changed it to match the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `z-index` of the image to -1 and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/kPtkd/1/

Comment: hmm thats strange as I was testing in IE8 and it worked, and now it's only working in IE8 compatibility mode. It could be an issue with JSFiddle, I sometimes have issues with it and IE. Either way it's strange

Comment: im about to just use transparent png placeholders... bad idea?

Comment: Found a way around it, not a great way though. Set a background colour on the div and it'll work. Tried background:transparent; but it didn't work :(

Comment: yea im going to need it transparent. :(

Comment: yeah transparent png to the rescue. You can use an IE8 conditional though to lessen the impact http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a position when using a z-index.

```
<img style="z-index:0;position:relative;" id="default_image" src="http://www.takeprideinutah.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/trees.jpg" alt=""/>
```

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Comment: declaring it doesnt make it work. Check out eh jsfiddle example

Comment: yes that doesnt work. It also doesnt account for why the border is selectable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving your links a greater z-index value:

```
a{
z-index:12;
}
```